# Rails 4 - checkbox agreement validation fails on create new user registration using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to include a "accept terms of service" checkbox (called `agreement`) on a form. The app is using `Devise` for the user management.

`views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` has:

```
<%= f.check_box :agreement, class: 'form-control' %>
```

The `application_controller.rb` has:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:agreement, :phone, :first_name, :last_name, :domain, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
```

Then in the `user.rb` controller, it has

```
# neither of the below worked
# validates :agreement, :acceptance => true
validates :agreement, acceptance: true
```

If I view the data in the `development.log`, it shows the `agreement` field coming through correctly with a value of 1, which is (according to the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance), the expected value for the validation):

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jFg6+ZDM1qldh020lv/FQHxlgZkby2dhUbejjXurr4w=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Joe", "last_name"=>"Smith", "phone"=>"2098993344", "domain"=>"google.com", "email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "agreement"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

However, any time the form is submitted it shows an error message that "Agreement must be accepted", whether it's checked or not.

Any ideas on what this is caused by?

Comment: Do you have an actual column in your table for `agreement`?

Comment: @BrandonCordell-- yes, it is a boolean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using this for your validation

`validates :agreement, acceptance: { accept: true }`

as per the Rails documentation

> :accept - Specifies value that is considered accepted. The default value is a string “1”, which makes it easy to relate to an HTML checkbox. **This should be set to true if you are validating a database column**, since the attribute is typecast from “1” to true before validation.

Comment: Thanks Brandon-- I did read the docs but misunderstood what they were getting at with that statement!

Comment: It's a little confusing to have to use `acceptance: { accept: true }`, seems a bit redundant when you first look at it. Glad it's working for you though!

Answer (score -1):

I had same scenerio like you did. This is how I accomplished similar to what you trying to do:

On routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Create new controller --> RegistrationsController.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
      if params[:agree] && verify_recaptcha
        super
      else
        build_resource(sign_up_params)
        clean_up_passwords(resource)
        if params[:agree].nil? && !verify_recaptcha
          flash.now[:alert] = "You did not agree and missing captcha"
        elsif params[:agree].nil?
          flash.now[:alert] = "You did not agree"
        elsif !verify_recaptcha
          flash.now[:alert] = "captcha not correct"
        end
        flash.delete :recaptcha_error
        render :new
      end
  end

end
```

and put the code on application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?

#accept additional attribute for user table
  def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(...)}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {|u| u.permit(..)}
  end
```